# Show that $A^TA=I=AA^T$ imposes $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ conditions on the elements of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I saw the following problem in a book.

> Show that for square matrices $A$ of order $n$, the orthogonality relation $A^TA=I=AA^T$ gives $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ conditions on its matrix elements.

There is something I can't exactly figure out. Everything is fine and dandy when I consider the relation $A^TA=I$. Suppose the matrix $A$ is made up of column vectors,

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} ↑ & ↑ & \cdots & ↑ \\
| & | & \cdots & | \\
\mathbf{v_1} & \mathbf{v_2} & \cdots & \mathbf{v_n} \\
| & | & \cdots & | \\
↓ & ↓ & \cdots & ↓
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then the relation $A^TA=I$, by matrix multiplication, translates to

$$\left<\mathbf{v_i},\mathbf{v_j}\right>=\begin{cases} 1 & i=j\,\,\textrm{[happens } n \textrm{ times]}\\ 0 & i\neq j\,\,\textrm{[happens } n(n-1) \textrm{ times]} \end{cases}$$

However, $\left<\mathbf{v_i},\mathbf{v_j}\right>=\left<\mathbf{v_j},\mathbf{v_i}\right>$, so the condition $\left<\mathbf{v_i},\mathbf{v_j}\right>=0$ really only happens $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ times. This gives a total number of conditions of

$$n+\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)=n(1+\frac{1}{2}n-\frac{1}{2})=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)}$$

**Here is where I am stuck.** Now consider the other relation, $AA^T=I$. If we write $A$ now in the exact same way we did earlier, this would impose $n(n-1)$ more conditions - that the $1\times n$ row vectors formed by taking the $i^{\textrm{th}}$ component of each of the $n$ original column vectors are all orthogonal. If this is indeed a new set of conditions, then we would have a new total number of conditions.

$$\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)+\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)=\frac{1}{2}n(n+3)\,\textrm{ ???}$$

Of course, this isn't correct. What have I done wrong? Certainly $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ must be distinct relations- that is, I don't think $AA^T=I$ implies $A^TA=I$, nor vice versa.

Please help me out!

Comment: What are 'conditions'?

Comment: A 'condition' on the elements of $A$ is an equation that involves any number of elements of $A$ that is independent of any other equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example take $n = 3.$  the matrix $B = AA^T$ is symmetric. so once you impose the condition on the lower part, i.e.$$ b_{11} = b_{22} = b_{33} =1 \text{ and } b_{21} = b_{31} = b_{32} = 0 $$ the symmetry takes care of the upper triangular part. the number of constraints are $$1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1) $$

Comment: I can't see how you got the equality relations $b_{21}=b_{31}=b_{32}$.

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan, they all need to be zero if $AA^T = I$

Comment: \*smacks face\* - Oh yeah, right.

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan, that must hurt.

Answer (score 3):

The matrix inverse is unique so you must have $AA^T = I$ as well, if and only if $A^TA = I$ and $A$ is square, because you basically assumed $A^T$ is the inverse. So your first case handles both cases. (i.e just substitute $A^T$ for $A$)

Comment: Hmmm alright I see what you're saying, but how do you directly explain the confusion spurred in the "**Here's where I'm stuck**" paragraph and onward? If $AA^T$ does indeed not impose any new conditions on the elements of $A$, then that must mean that the row vectors formed by the same element (first, second, $n^{\textrm{th}}$) are orthogonal, but I can't see a way to show that directly.

Answer (score 1):

$A A^T = I \Leftrightarrow A^T A A^T = A^T \Leftrightarrow A^T A = I$

you could also see this because

$A^T A = (A A^T)^T = I^T = I $

Comment: Wait I thought you could only say that $(A^TA)A^T=A^T \implies A^TA=I$ if you also know that $A^T(A^TA)=A^T$ (basically that this proclaimed identity matrix $A^TA$ is commutative).

Comment: However, I can't see anything wrong with your second line. Thanks by the way!

Comment: In general $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$ so $(AA^T)^T = AA^T$. Your second argument misleadingly suggests that $(AA^T)^T = A^T A$ in general, which is false. This is only true here because $A$ and $A^T$ are mutually inverse!